# Getting "undefined" error when expecting a value from "el.dom.innerText" call

Tags: javascript

JS Code:

```
var a = {
    innerText: function (id) {
        ST.element(row + DnDTarget.gridRow(id))
            .and(function (el) {
                console.log(el.dom.innerText); // Outputs InnerText value 
                return el.dom.innerText;
        });
    }
}

var beforeText = a.innerText(1);
console.log(beforeText) // outputs undefined
```

How do I return `el.dom.innerText`? I even tried putting it inside a variable and then return it, But that didn't work as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Maybe add another `return` before `ST.element`. It should look like this `innerText: function(id){ return ST.element .........`

Comment: No.. sadly that didn't work :(